# Android Studio "Open Declaration" like eclipse

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

Is there a function like the "open declaration" in eclipse, that we can use in the new Android Studio?

Just like `F3` button.

Comment: There are 158 people that think different from you (check out the android-studio tag). If you don't have anything useful to say please don't comment.

Comment: While I won't go so far as to say that this is off-topic, right now most of Android Studio is standard IntellJ IDEA. Hence, unless you are fairly certain that the feature in question is unique to Android Studio, you should be focused on learning how to perform the operations in IDEA, most of which should be transferable to Android Studio.

Comment: @Simon There isn't a simple quick answer on google and I know I would be happy to find it in SO. If this question is not of your interest you can just ignore it instead of trying to educate people that probably won't listen to you.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, I will check that.

Comment: ctrl+click or ctrl+B

Comment: It is hidden under "Go To" on the right-click menu (I was expecting it to be at the top level)

Comment: If the declaration is found in another file, can it be opened in a split screen?

Comment: Not Ctrl-B but Cmd-B for macOS. Doh.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Here are more details to help you avoid asking the same question for all the other commands:

Press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + A</kbd>, and search for the command you're looking for ("declaration") for example. This finds the command "Declaration - Goto by Reference action - <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd>".

So you just need to put your cursor on the method you want to go to, and press <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd>? You can also <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> to achieve the same goal.

The most useful keyboard shortcuts are described in the *Help - Tip of the day* dialog box. Read them all.

Comment: Thank you for nice explanation. Its so annoying that each every company sets their own default shortcuts for such a basic things like this. Eclipse has F3, Visual Studio has F12, and now android studio is Ctrl+B. Silly me i didn't test the Ctrl+Click. Thats same as in Delphi.

Comment: ctrl shift a did nothing

Answer (score 10):

In IntelliJ-IDEA it's `Right-Click` => `Go To` => `Declaration`. As others noted, Android Studio is based on IntelliJ-IDEA and in most of the cases, the experience would be the same.

Answer (score 10):

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or
2. Right click, Go to -> Declaration
3. For Mac: <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

In Preferences, I added the shortcut to Navigate->Declaration in Keymap:

[image: Android Studio/IntelliJ Keymap screen -> add a shortcut for Declaration]

The cmd+button1 click was added with right click, "add mouse shortcut".

It is interesting, that to make it 'fully' eclipse like, you may want to make the Javadocs appear on hover. For that you must set "Show quick doc on mouse move" up in the Editor->Other section.

[image: Setting up Show quick doc on mouse move in Editor->Other section]

Comment: Worked for me. For Android Studio File->settings->Implementation and give your preferred keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You can click middle mouse button and android studio open declaration or all usage locations of method/variable;

Comment: This is the best solution for those who are just browsing code one handed with just a mouse, as all other options require 'ctrl' + something.

Answer (score 0):

^B on the variable.

There is, but it doesn't work sometimes (unlike Eclispe where it always works). Build project. Searches don't work when using Find Usages nor Go to Implementation etc. Free text searches do work. seems to be a disconnect in how AS loads the gradle projects.

The good news is if you create a brand new project with all the defaults then these things work. The project we have was ported from Eclipse to Android Studio by a mobile consultancy based in Austin; so, looks like the porting process is not clean.

In conclusion, the project in which these did not work was fixed by using Import, by using Java 7 (had to fix class path, delete Oracle symlink, etc), and by installing a git client and setting it up to run from the command line. After that, the project not only can be imported but features such as Go To->Declaration started working. And the "NullException" messages which occurred often in Android Studio went away.

Comment: Also, Reopening a project does not close the corrent project and open the selected project. Maybe this is just Android Studio and not IntelliJ. Feels like using a 1/2 backed IDE from 1992. Probably worst IDE I've used since then in terms of stuff basically, simply, not working.

Comment: Probably due to the "StackOverflowError: null" which is seen in the bottom left status bar almost constantly when running Android Studio. Windows 7 Pro SP 1 (6.1). java version "1.8.0_31". Yes, have also tried with older java versions.

Comment: Also want to point out that in addition to things simply not working, also things are often very slow. For instance, creating a new project from scratch with just the defaults takes over a minute. Compare that to maybe 10 seconds in IDE's 20 years ago.

Comment: So, there are 3 options when trying to run an Android Studio project in Android Studio.

Comment: So, there are 4 options when trying to run an Android Studio project in Android Studio. 1. Open an existing Android Studi project. DOES NOT WORK when Go To->Declaratoin. 2. Import, use gradle config. DOES NOT WORK for find declaration. When building one gets this error: Error:Android Source Generator: [unionbank-android] AndroidManifest.xml file not found.  3. Import using maven config. Various options in there.   DOES NOT WORK when Go To->Declaratoin Actually only imports 1 of the 4 projects despite being told to search recursively. 4. Import->Create . from existing. Next does not even work

Answer (score 0):

File - Settings - Keymap - Eclipse 
sets all shortcuts "Eclipse like"