# How to open import

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I saw on a youtube video with tutorial about programming as the person indicated the import (example `import android.view.View`)  and use the shortcut on keyboard and then he see what is inside.
I would like to know how to do this in `AndroidStudio`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio "Open Declaration" like eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632727/android-studio-open-declaration-like-eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows: For Android Studio

Hold `CTRL` Key + `LEFT Click Mouse button` to show the detail of the class

Comment: left click in my pc

Comment: know it, no problem