# Android Studio 3.1 does not resolve reference by CTRL+CLICK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

I had updated my `Android Studio` yesterday, and wondering that Resolving resource by CTRL+CLICK is not working as it was working in earlier versions.

Please consider a line written below:

```
 mBinder.fabCart.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Previously when I was doing "CTLR+CLICK" on fabCart is was taking me to the XML.
But in `Android Studio 3.1` I can not reach to there directly. I need to go to setContentView and by clicking on Layout File Name "CTRL+CLICK works"

Also when I write:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.fabCart:
                break;
        }
    }
```

From here "CTRL+CLICK" works as expected.

Can anyone let me know how to enable/set resolve references same as earlier versions?

Comment: Do invalidate catches and restart android studio.

Comment: Did it many times, not working. Also tried for resetting settings for studio.

Comment: does this happens in all project's or newly created project?

Comment: Yes for all My projects.

Comment: check this -->> https://stackoverflow.com/a/29263860/4146722

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 8):

Invalidate caches and restart android studio works for my case.

```
File -> Invalidate caches or Restart -> Invalidate caches and Restart
```

Answer (score 3):

Try upgrading the kotlin_version to the latest version

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, solved my problem.
If you update plugin of Kotlin, and don't change reference to latest one in project gradle file. then you might experience this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

File --- settings --- keymap --- under Keymaps select eclipse

Or in the searchbox type jump and there you can find option to change key combination.

Comment: Also changing keymap to eclipse will change all the shortcuts to eclipse.

Comment: Exactly that i dont want to do, I want to keep studio key maps but only this reference resolver to work properly.

Comment: Actually till 3.0.1 it is all working fine. It seems to be encounter in 3.1 only. I haven't made any change in setting for 3.1 just updated from updates

Comment: All and not only for me. for all of my colleague as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading the gradle dependency to the latest version. My version is com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0

I ran into a similar issue on Android Studio 3.3 with only kotlin files. Java files were working fine. I noticed new projects were fine with kotlin so I checked which dependencies were different. My gradle versions were not matching.